# NameError in IdeasController#index uninitialized constant Idea::PictureUploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following this [tutorial](http://guides.railsgirls.com/app/), and I'm getting this error: `uninitialized constant Idea::PictureUploader`. This happened in step 4, after I ran `rails generate uploader Picture` and added `mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader` to app/models/idea.rb.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I followed the tutorial precisely and didn't get any error until that point. I did refresh my server before running it.

**app/models/idea.rb**

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base     
     mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

Comment: `rails generate uploader Picture` should have created a `app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb` file with class `PictureUploader`.  Do you have it?

Comment: No, I don't. I guess generating the uploader didn't work the first time I did it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart the server after creating the uploader?

Comment: Just restart sever. That worked for me.